# How to enter additional data entered in text files in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I'm currently working on a project where new orders are added to text files and the details of these orders must be displayed in text boxes.

I managed to get the application for 'Order 1' but I am unsure as to how to display details for orders that have not yet been added to the text files e.g. Order 20.

```
Private Sub btnDisplay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisplay.Click

    Dim query = IO.File.ReadAllLines("Order1.txt")
    Dim name = query(0).Split(","c)(0)
    Dim address = query(0).Split(","c)(1)
    Dim phonenum = query(0).Split(","c)(2)
    Dim method = query(0).Split(","c)(3)

    txtName.Text = name
    txtAddress.Text = address
    txtPhoneNum.Text = phonenum
    txtMethod.Text = method

End Sub
```

Comment: VBA or VB.NET? You've mentioned one in the title and tagged the other. They are not the same language. Please clarify the technology you're using. From the code sample I'll guess VB.NET but you should always make sure you use the right terminology! Thanks.

Comment: Sorry! VB.net..

Comment: Ok thanks. Now "I am unsure as to how to display details for orders that have not yet been added"...it's not really clear what you mean here. If an order doesn't exist, what are you going to display? Are you really asking how to display an empty form for someone to enter new order data?

Comment: P.S. Using one file per order is going to get very messy when you have more than a handful. You might be better with a single file which stores all orders in a structured format e.g. CSV, JSON, XML, something like that. TBH though a small database (even just a file-based thing like SQLite) would probably be easier to manage. That way you can much more easily query your data (e.g. find a specific order by some property of it like name or ID, or count your orders, or add up the total revenue). Storing data in files is a very crude solution if this is anything more than just a tutorial exercise

Comment: There is another form where the user can enter data and this data will be written in a textfile e.g. Order 20 will be sent to the textfile 'Order20.txt'.  This is just a summary of the order where the user can only see the order information. I am not sure how to display the new order when new orders are added.

Comment: You mean you want to display all existing orders at once? You'd need to loop through all the files in the directory where you store orders (since you don't know how many there will be) and for each one of those, output the data onto the screen. If the data is a read-only summary then don't bother creating textboxes etc, just output it all into a label or something. Also it would be a bit simpler if you just store all the orders in one file though - then you can just loop through all the lines in the file instead.

Comment: As I mentioned though I really recommend you re-think your storage format before you go any further

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if I understand correctly what you want.

```
Private Sub btnDisplay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisplay.Click

    Dim yourModelLists As New List(yourModel)

    Do
        Dim query = IO.File.ReadLine("Order1.txt")
        Dim yourModelItem As yourModel

        If Not (String.IsNullOrEmpty(query) Or String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(query) Then
            Dim column As Integer = 0
            Dim items As String() = query.Split(";")

            For Each item In items
                If Not (String.IsNullOrEmpty(item) Or String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item)) Then
                    Select Case column
                        Case 0
                            yourModelItem.name = item
                        Case 1
                            yourModelItem.address = item
                        Case 2
                            yourModelItem.phonenum = item
                        Case 3
                            yourModelItem.method = item
                        Case Else
                            'Do something
                    End Select
                End If
            Next
        End If

        yourModelLists.Add(yourModelItem)

    Loop Until (String.IsNullOrEmpty(query) Or String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(query))

End Sub
```

All you need is in yourModelLists.